# Navigation Bar at Bottom

Tags: iphone

Can we have NavigationBar at the bottom of the screen.As i have to display a image at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put one anywhere but the system will not manage it for you.

If you want to put a nav bar at the bottom of the screen though, the chances are great you really want to have a toolbar, or a tab bar...  navigation controllers are just not good on the bottom and users will think it's really wierd.

Can't you just make the nav bar transparent and have the image go behind it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UINavigationBar`'s `initWithFrame:` to position it how you would like. You could also put it inside a view which is located below your image.

It might be worth using a toolbar instead. Users are used to seeing the navigation bar at the top. The interface guidelines might "require" this too which could lead to fun when you submit your application to Apple.